# JS (arrow) factory functions

Tags: javascript, methods, properties

For a homework problem, I need to write a function called `addSquareMethod`. Below is the textbook solution:

```js
 const addSquareMethod = (arr) => {
     return arr.map(val => {
       val.square = function () {
         return this.total * this.total;
       };
       return val;
     });
   };
```

When I run this in Google Chrome dev tools, it produces the following,

```js
addSquareMethod([1,2,3]);
>>>
[1, 2, 3]
0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
length: 3__proto__: Array(0)
```

However, when I defined a function on my own, that seemed more intuitive, I got a different result:

```js
function addSquareMethod(arr){
        for (let j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
            arr[j] = arr[j]**2;
        }
        return arr;
    };

addSquareMethod([1,2,3]);
>>>
[1, 4, 9]
0: 1
1: 4
2: 9
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Can someone explain what the textbook solution is doing?

Edit: Thanks to comments and answers at time of writing this. I understand now that the function the textbook defined is looking for an array of objects, rather than primitives. `[{total:1},{total:2},{total:3}]`.

I've changed the architecture accordingly and it seems to be working!

```
function addSquareMethod(arr){
        for (let j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
            arr[j].square = arr[j].total**2;
        }
        return arr;
    };
```

Comment: Because the original method is mapping the elements to new values, which does not change the original.  `arr[j] = arr[j]**2;` is assigning a result back on to the original

Comment: Just for the record, the textbook solution is poor. I suggest finding another textbook. There's absolutely no reason to use `map` there, and doing so is misleading.

Comment: @Taplar, Oh I see. Out of curiosity, when I execute `addSquareMethod([1,2,3])[0].square` I get undefined. Shouldn't the textbook's code be creating a `square` property that can be accessed?

Comment: It looks like your two code blocks are also not the same and you are calling the first one incorrectly.  `return this.total * this.total;` from the first snippet suggests you are not giving it an array of primative numbers, but an array of objects that have a key of `total` in them

Answer (score 1):

The textbook solution seems bad because it doesnt explain how to use it.

The textbook solution uses map to add a 'square' method/function to each element (object with a number attribute 'total'), containing the square value of the 'total' attribute of the element.

Your solution changes the original array values (numbers) to their squares.

Using the textbook solution you can do:

```
let arr = [{total:1},{total:2},{total:3}]
arr = addSquareMethod(arr)

console.log(arr[1].total) //2
console.log(arr[1].square()) //4
console.log(arr[1].total) //2 , doesnt change original value
```

If you wanna modify your example to use map like the textbook one, you can do it like so:

```
const addSquareMethod = (arr) => {
     return arr.map(val => {
       return val*val;
     });
   };

let arr = [1,2,3]
console.log(arr[1]) //2
arr = addSquareMethod(arr)
console.log(arr[1]) //4
```